# Are Japanese watermelons crispy?

Tags: anime-production, japanese-language, haikyuu

In the anime Haikyuu (second season to be specific) when Karasuno High goes to tokyo for a week for practice matches, there is a scene where some high school girls brings watermelons for the players.

In the next scene, Hinata is shown eating one of those, and the sound effect is like eating chips or something crispy. Is it sound effect fault or japanese watermelons are crispy?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the following are onomatopoeias (words expressing sounds which the Japanese language is abundant with) for eating watermelons / crispy thing.

- watermelon : *shaku shaku* (シャクシャク) [a sound effect sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGc5GLW1deI)
- crispy thing : *kari kari* or *pari pari* (カリカリ or パリパリ) [a sound effect sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mq-l5NGjVO4)

I haven't watched the scene, but it is unlikely to be a fault. And I can assure you that Japanese watermelons are not crispy.

The answer to your question is that they might simply sound similar. The difference is the so-called plosive sounds such as  *p* or *k* for crisps.